# Boost Issues: erfc

Tags: c++, boost, compilation

I'm working with a third party library that makes use of boost::math and the special functions portions in particular. The one file uses the following include:

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/fpclassify.hpp>
```

Which produces a really strange compilation error:

> /usr/include/boost_1_58_0/boost/math/special_functions/detail/igamma_large.hpp:265:14: error: 'erfc' is not a member of 'boost::math'

Except it clearly is, as it's defined in boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp

This is one of many such internal reference errors, and I'm sure they're all related. What am I missing here?

Comment: What are we missing? The self-contained reproducer. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/615b4209bc588c40 - Probably also compiler version/platform/architecture/build options

Comment: Not sure a self-contained reproducer is going to capture this one, the linked dependencies are too deep.

Comment: More important: not self contained examples are not capturing anything. You have a problem. You want it sorted. Therefore: ***isolate it***. This is not optional. You can't solve an unknown problem (except by accident).

Comment: See e.g. http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/; Even if you fail to reproduce it with _n_ subsets of the problem, this gives you information about where the problem -does- lie

Comment: Yep, I agree completely! I created a new barebones project that simply instantiates the main object from this library, and it built just fine, which led me to compare compilation options. Sure enough adding the compiler directives to the second project caused the same issues, so now I have to work out which one is causing the problem and if I can get away without using it in the first place.